# Проблема с запуском selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox('d:\\1\\geckodriver')
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

Ошибка при работе с selenium. Пробую начать работать с этой библиотекой. Установила geckodriver, прописала в переменной PATH, выдает ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\proba1.py", line 6, in
>   
>       browser = webdriver.Firefox('d:\1\geckodriver')   File "C:\Users\Sylwia.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
>   line 164, in **init**
>       self.service.start()   File "C:\Users\Sylwia.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 104, in start
>       raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can
>   not connect to the Service geckodriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть догадка, что проблема в сопоставлении 127.0.0.1 и localhost, подобная проблема обсуждалась вот тут:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843575/python3selenium-raise-message-can-not-connect-to-the-service-geckodriver

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2903

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/270

Все очевидцы говорят, что необходимо правильное сопоставление 127.0.0.1 и localhost или через hosts на компьютере, или через настройку DNS резолвера.

Раз уж вы на Винде, попробуйте глянуть в C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts строку "127.0.0.1       localhost" в конце файла, по дефолту она должна быть закомментирована. Если она у вас закомментирована, попробуйте её раскомментировать для явного указания сопоставления, перезагрузиться и попробовать запустить Селениум