# Selenium при запуске появляется окно и ничего не происходит geckodriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Появляется окно и не исчезает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

Comment: Происходит и очень много. Например, выводится текст ошибки, который нужно прочитать и принять к сведению.

Comment: Судя по тому, что вы публикуете второй вопрос с (предположительно) похожими ситуациями, вероятно мой ответ на ваш первый вопрос вам не помог. И если это так, то что-бы мы могли вам помочь, прошу более подробно описать все процесс того что вы делаете с самого начала)) и начинайте с версии системы на который вы это пробуете, потом то как вы поставили python, то как вы установили selenium, то какой GECKODRIVER и куда вы скачивали, и как вы его прописали в PATH.

Comment: Мы с радостью вам поможем, но так же как и вы, никто не хочет делать пустую работу. И даже если ваш первый вопрос не получил должного ответа, не смотря на то что ответ засчитан как ответ)))) то в этом вопросе вы могли бы упомянуть что что-то уже попробовали и это что-то вам не помогло. Учитесь учится, за вас знания и опыт никто не получит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходим указать путь до Geckodriver

```
ff = "" Путь до драйвера
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ff)
```

Скачать можно [здесь](https://github.com/Mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Comment: Это второй подобный вопрос пользователя, и в предыдущем (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899105/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-selenium) было описано, что Gecko уже есть в Path. Есть конечно вероятность, что сам Геко был скачан "откуданибудь", и это совсем не Геко)))